# Getting UI elements by type from Control array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, javafx

Is there a way to loop through Control array and get only one type of UI elements, for example, `TextField`s? Here is an array which contains `TextField`s, `DatePicker`s, and `ChoiceBox`es:

```
Control[] allControls = new Control[] {
     name, surname, age, address, city,
     telephoneNum, email, deptBox, idNum, startDate,
     contractType, endDate, payFreq, accountNum, taxCoeficient,
     netSalary 
};
```

Is there a way to put `if` condition in `for` loop and get only one type of UI elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca use `instanceof` with a loop like this :

```
List<Control> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(Control item : allControls){
    if(item instanceof TextField){
        list.add(c);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

> Can you use getText() method on items from new list? How to access
>   values of Control items?

Yes you can cast your item to `TextField` then you can use `getText()` like this :

```
List<TextField> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Control item : list) {
    String text = ((TextField) item).getText();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

---

To avoid all this you can create a List of `TextField` from begginig like this :

```
List<TextField> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Control item : allControls) {
    if (item instanceof TextField) {
        list.add((TextField) item);
    }
}
```

So you can easily use `item.getText()` without casting.

Comment: Can you use getText() method on items from new list? How to access values of Control items?

Comment: @Kvark900 you can cast your item to `(TextField) item` so you can use `getText()` like `((TextField) item).getText()`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to filter all instance being of the desired class using `instanceof` and finally collect them to a new List:

```
List<TextField> textFieldList = Arrays.asList(allControls).stream()
    .filter(c -> c instanceof TextField)
    .map (c -> (TextField) c)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```